# Trying to shift my background color to the right

Tags: html, css, background, html-lists, shift

So, my background color for my `<ul>` is causing the strip of color to go off the page, and I'm extremely OCD and need it to align perfectly on each side. I shift it over with padding, but only the right side gets the amount of space I need, the left padding only pushes the padding on the right over more to the left.

Is there a way that I can shift my background color over to the right, so I can align things how I want? Can I do it without creating another list?

Here is the code:

```css
ul,
li {
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 300px;
  line-height: 10px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 66px;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #216064;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="round1.html"> Round 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="round2">Round 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="round3">Round 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="round4">Round 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="round5">Round 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="round6">Round 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="round7">Round 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="transactions">Transactions</a></li>
</ul>
```

- Round 1
- Round 2
- Round 3
- Round 4
- Round 5
- Round 6
- Round 7
- Transactions

```
ul, li {
    display:inline;
    margin-top: 300px;
    line-height: 10px;
    padding-left: 80px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-right: 66px;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #216064;

}
```

I am also just starting out, so I apologize if there are things there that are not needed.

Comment: actually, I don't know if this is what you wanted but here is a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cpffn2qh/

Comment: I think the overflow comment helped line it up to the border around the whole body, but if there is a way I can put a bit of space between the left and right edges, just to make it a little more visually appealing, that would be great!

Thanks, lol easy fix, I still have a lot to learn.